# Connect using sqlplus to db server through multiple tunnels

Tags: ssh, tunnel, sqldeveloper

I would like to create an SQL Developer connection to a database through a couple of tunnels.

The steps right now are:

Connect to server A -> connect to server B -> run sqlplus against tnsname on a server that I do not have ssh access to.

Is there an easy way of using SQL Developer instead of sqlplus? I have read through >20 articles on the subject and still have no idea how to actually make the connection.

I understand that you can chain ssh -L commands to get the server connection, but I don't know how to use that connection in SQL Developer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create your tunnel like so:

```
ssh -L 1521:server_b:1521 -N server_a
```

The first 1521 is the local port you want to bind to, so you can change that as you want. Then in sqldeveloper connect to `localhost:1521` (where 1521 is, again, the local port you chose).

Of course if you're on Windows you can create the tunnel with PuTTY. The Session host would be `server_a`, and then you go to Connection → SSH → Tunnels and enter 1521 as your Source port, and the Destination is `server_b:1521`. Make sure you press Add after entering the info, then you can open the connection.